# moodle advanced grading: marking guide, making default criteria zero

Tags: moodle

In order to correct students assignment and award marks for question-wise, the [marking guide](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Marking_guide) under advanced grading methods are very useful.
I have  25 questions. As this method does not allow any fields to be blank I have to manually mark zero in all fields every time even if I m correcting only few questions at a given time. Is there anyway I can tweak so that default mark is zero or empty?